# Database-first Add Controller not getting current model list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've recently dropped and added a few tables from my database-first generated model (asp.net mvc4).

Now, when i try to create a controller (via context menu add controller), and try to choose the new "Client" model from the list of available models, the dropdown list is out of sync, showing some old models that had been dropped still, but not showing any of the newly added models. (screenshot below)

What can I do to get this list of models updated so that I can continue?  I've tried restarting VS, but the problem persists.

Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to rebuild the project for any new classes to show up.

Comment: Oh...BAH!   I'm blaming this kerfuffle on my cold..I can't think straight...yeah, that's it :D